# run thread respectively in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to run 2 threads respectively but it doesn't run respectively. Here is my code:

```
static int shared = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i){
                if (true){
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println("thread"+ 1 +" : shared = " + shared++);
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i){
                if (true){
                    lock.lock();
                    System.out.println("thread"+ 2 +" : shared = " + shared++);
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

}
```

thread 1 runs about 20 - 30 times and then thread 2 runs 20 - 30 times. How to make it run thread 1 then thread 2 and so on.

Comment: don't start thread 2 until thread 1 finishes: `t1.start(); t1.join(); t2.start();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) and a share `flag`.

When `flag` is `ture`, let thread1 run and thread2 wait.

When `flag` is `flase`, let thread2 run and thread1 wait.

After they finishing their part, they set the `flag` and `sigal` the other.

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Solution {

    static int shared = 0;
    static boolean flag = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i) {
                    lock.lock();
                    while (flag == false) {
                        try {
                            condition.await();  // wait until thread2 set true
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("thread" + 1 + " : shared = " + shared++);
                    flag = false;
                    condition.signalAll();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i) {
                    lock.lock();
                    while (flag == true) {
                        try {
                            condition.await(); // wait until thread1 set false
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("thread" + 2 + " : shared = " + shared++);
                    flag = true;
                    condition.signalAll();
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution works perfect, but why thread 1 runs first but thread 2 is the one to print to the console first

Comment: @Lirus Because thread1 only runs when the flag is false. You can set it freely, see my update.

Comment: i got it, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your lock is not "fair" you can try the same with:

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Fairness means giving the lock to the thread that has waited for the longest time. When you have two threads they will switch each-other.

It would be an easy solution which is not 100% guaranteed. I think for 2 threads that should be alright :)

> The constructor for this class accepts an optional fairness parameter.
>   When set true, under contention, locks favor granting access to the
>   longest-waiting thread. Otherwise this lock does not guarantee any
>   particular access order. Programs using fair locks accessed by many
>   threads may display lower overall throughput (i.e., are slower; often
>   much slower) than those using the default setting, but have smaller
>   variances in times to obtain locks and guarantee lack of starvation.
>   **Note however, that fairness of locks does not guarantee fairness of
>   thread scheduling.** Thus, one of many threads using a fair lock may
>   obtain it multiple times in succession while other active threads are
>   not progressing and not currently holding the lock. Also note that the
>   untimed tryLock() method does not honor the fairness setting. It will
>   succeed if the lock is available even if other threads are waiting.

Comment: You can not guarantee they will try auqire the lock  respectively. Make it fair can not solve this problem.

Comment: you're right, it's not 100% but it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer you can always accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `join()` method. Example:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });

        thread.setName("Thread 1");

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        });

        thread2.setName("Thread 2");

        thread.start();
        thread.join();
        thread2.start();
```

output (after 10sec wait):

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
```